# pecl install always failed "unable to connect to ssl://pecl.php.net:443 (Unknown error) in Proxy.php on line 183"

Tags: php, macos, pecl

```
qiulangs-MacBook-Pro:extensions qiulang$ pecl -vvv install debug

Warning: fsockopen(): SSL: Handshake timed out in Proxy.php on line 183

Warning: fsockopen(): Failed to enable crypto in Proxy.php on line 183

Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://pecl.php.net:443 (Unknown error) in Proxy.php on line 183
No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/debug"
Cannot initialize 'channel://pecl.php.net/debug', invalid or missing package file
Package "channel://pecl.php.net/debug" is not valid
install failed
```

I used brew to install php 7.2 and 7.3 and tried both pecl with them, but I got the same error.

While my colleague can use pecl (also using brew install php@7.2) without any problem. So it must be something wrong with my setting.

```
qiulangs-MacBook-Pro:sbin qiulang$ php -r "print_r(openssl_get_cert_locations());"
Array
(
    [default_cert_file] => /usr/local/libressl-2.2/etc/ssl/cert.pem
    [default_cert_file_env] => SSL_CERT_FILE
    [default_cert_dir] => /usr/local/libressl-2.2/etc/ssl/certs
    [default_cert_dir_env] => SSL_CERT_DIR
    [default_private_dir] => /usr/local/libressl-2.2/etc/ssl/private
    [default_default_cert_area] => /usr/local/libressl-2.2/etc/ssl
    [ini_cafile] =>
    [ini_capath] =>
)
```

Comment: Please post the output to the following command: `php -r "print_r(openssl_get_cert_locations());"`

Comment: Yes, please check my updated question. Thanks!

Comment: Does [this code](https://gist.github.com/ParityError/e39717cd8b1efe6593a8d190dd8eef0a) successfully connect for you? The issue you have is related to the `SSL`, although it's not clear which part yet. Is there some reason why you are using `LibreSSL`? My guess is that it's directly related to that.

Comment: I run that codes got the same error Warning: fsockopen(): SSL: Handshake timed out in /Users/qiulang/Dev/php/logs/pecl_test.php on line 2 and PHP Warning:  fsockopen(): Failed to enable crypto in /Users/qiulang/Dev/php/logs/pecl_test.php on line 2

Comment: If I remember I used that ssl lib to build a sliqte3 version myself.

Comment: I believe that the problem is most likely stemming from `LibreSSL` since it doesn't adhere to standards Apple requires of current `macOS`. You'll probably want to uninstall it and use either `OpenSSL` or the Apple default crypto library, which normally is called through an openssl symlink. The normal SSL cert locations can be found shown in the output of [this example](https://gist.github.com/ParityError/2360d5628d9e8a9a7e699ed63e19c68a).

Comment: I used brew update openssl to latest, but still hit the same error. I gave up :( I wanted pecl to install xdebug, but I will just compile xdebug myself.

Comment: If you run the script again does it have the same paths? That needs to change before it will work. You could also change it in your `php.ini` I suppose (eg. `openssl.cafile=/private/etc/ssl/cert.pem`)

Comment: Indeed I did not set openssl.cafile=/private/etc/ssl/cert.pem, with that I can run the test code successfully. But when run pecl install I still hit the same error. I really gave up. I just taught myself php in last 24 hours. Too much info :(

Comment: Yes, as said that `LibreSSL` needs to be removed and your `$PATH` needs to be fixed. You'll likely continue to encounter issues as long as it's lingering on your system. Good luck!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187229/discussion-between-qiulang-and-lll).